# MUcomplete autocompletion interface with VimTex plugin works with \cite{ but not with \ref{

Tags: vim, autocomplete, latex

My vimrc is thus:

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
    silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
        \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
    autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
Plug 'lifepillar/vim-mucomplete'
call plug#end()

set completeopt+=menuone
set completeopt+=noselect
let g:mucomplete#enable_auto_at_startup = 1

let g:mucomplete#can_complete = {}
let g:mucomplete#can_complete.tex = { 'omni': { t -> t =~# g:vimtex#re#neocomplete . '$' } }
```

I have taken the suggestion for `can_complete.tex` from official [VimTex documentation](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt) with respect to having `MUcomplete` interact with `VimTex`.

I have the following content in `bibfile.bib`:

```
@Article{somekey,
  title     = {A super awesome paper}
}
```

With this configuration, I am able to have `MUcomplete` work fine for triggering automatic completion suggestion when `\cite{` is typed and the option provided is `somekey` from the bibliography file.

However, on typing `\ref{` in the hope of triggering automatic completion suggestions of equation labels in the `.tex` file, it fails to work.

Animated gif of the `.tex` file follows:

[image]

Is it possible to figure out why this could be the case and how to have have autocompletion triggered automatically as one types `\ref{`?

To aid in possibly reproducing the issue, here is the content of the `.tex` file shown in the animated gif:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    \text{ }& asdfasdf              &&\quad\nonumber\\
    \text{ }&89999\times 45\leq 88  &&\quad \forall\label{eq:1}\\
        &abc                        &&\quad\exists\label{eq:okay}\\
        &\times x                   &&\quad\forall\nonumber\\
        &abcd                       &&\quad\nonumber
\end{alignat}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibfile.bib}

\end{document}
```

Output of `:echo g:vimtex#re#neocomplete` is

`\v\\%(%(\a*cite|Cite)\a*\*?%(\s*\[[^]]*\]){0,2}\s*\{[^}]*|%(\a*cites|Cites)%(\s*\([^)]*\)){0,2}%(%(\s*\[[^]]*\]){0,2}\s*\{[^}]*\})*%(\s*\[[^]]*\]){0,2}\s*\{[^}]*|bibentry\s*\{[^}]*|%(text|block)cquote\*?%(\s*\[[^]]*\]){0,2}\s*\{[^}]*|%(for|hy)\w*cquote\*?\{[^}]*}%(\s*\[[^]]*\]){0,2}\s*\{[^}]*|defbibentryset\{[^}]*}\{[^}]*|\a*ref%(\s*\{[^}]*|range\s*\{[^,}]*%(}\{)?)|hyperref\s*\[[^]]*|includegraphics\*?%(\s*\[[^]]*\]){0,2}\s*\{[^}]*|%(include%(only)?|input|subfile)\s*\{[^}]*|([cpdr]?(gls|Gls|GLS)|acr|Acr|ACR)\a*\s*\{[^}]*|(ac|Ac|AC)\s*\{[^}]*|includepdf%(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{[^}]*|includestandalone%(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{[^}]*|%(usepackage|RequirePackage|PassOptionsToPackage)%(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{[^}]*|documentclass%(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{[^}]*|begin%(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{[^}]*|end%(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{[^}]*|\a*)`

Comment: You can't possibly expect random people to install your specific combination of niche plugins just to answer your questions. Try the vimtex issue tracker instead.

Comment: Fair enough. It is also possible that some folks already have met with this issue before with these two plugins and could have figured out the reason and the fix. Have raised the issue with both plugins' issue trackers on github.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved [here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/2525)

Essentially, one should have compiled the `.tex` file once as autocompletion of `\ref{` requires parsing the `.aux` file that is generated only after compiling the document once.